# validate id token in Quarkus oidc extension

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, quarkus

I have some questions regarding the Quarkus oidc extension for validating access to a service (not an oidc client, so I am not calling OIDC flows, only validating tokens):

In addition to validating the JWT access token (authorization bearer token), is it possible to validate the id token, defined in another header? (in my case x-id-token)

Would additional claims in the ID token be accessible somehow, for example through SecurityIdentity or something else?
I would like to avoid having to call the userInfo endpoint every time.

Also, in my case, the id token contains "groups", that I would have liked to be mapped to roles to be used in @RolesMapping: is this possible? In Microprofile JWT, for non-OpenID Connect cases, it seems like the groups claim is defined on the access token, but in OIDC from my interpretation, it seems logical that this kind of information is on the id token, isn't it?
I tried adding "quarkus.oidc.roles.source=idtoken" on my app, but this seems to be limited to oidc client applications.

Also, perhaps it's just me, but I am confused by the doc for OIDC for services (https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect), regarding what is client OIDC and what is server-side validation for services: this page seems to be focused on services, but then the configuration part references a lot of configuration properties that concern client applications that must call the OIDC endpoints, OIDC flows, etc. Am I missing / misunderstanding something?

(Note: otherwise the extension is great! And multi-tenancy is very useful…and is also the first reason why we initially preferred using this extension instead of the Quarkus Smallrye JWT)

Thank you.